# Recover registry keys to "offline" hive

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry

I'm sure this has been asked before, but I can't find it.

My computer died, and in the process of trying to set up a new one, I accidentally deleted all the registry keys from my old account (on the old drive).  I exported them as a `.reg` via [Yaru](https://www.tzworks.net/prototype_page.php?proto_id=3), as per many suggestions, but I can't figure out how to load them back *into* the old hive.  I want the old system to remain as it was, in case that computer gets repaired.

So, I can import into the live system, but that's not what I'm trying do to here.  I can load the (tiny) amount of data that's left in the old hive, but I can't import into it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What? If you deleted the keys then they are gone.  There is nothing left to import

Comment: Yaru can recover deleted keys (see [here](http://www.techradar.com/us/news/computing-components/how-to-undelete-a-registry-key-1051589) for example).  I have the `.reg` that contains them all.  I want to put them back, but *not* into the current hive, which is what all the instructions I've seen have directions for.

Comment: If you don't want to replace the current hive what hive exactly do you want to replace?  Its not clearl what you mean "old" hive.

Comment: Can you successfully load the old HKCU/HKLM hive(s) into Regedit on the live system?

Comment: @Ramhound - I want to take the hive living on my original hard drive from the dead system (the "old hive") and restore its own deleted keys back to it.

Comment: @techie007 - Yes, although it's almost empty as far as regedit is concerned (there were 2-3 keys that couldn't be deleted)

Comment: I did have a thought - it's only HKCU that's messed up.  Once the dead machine is repaired, can I boot and log in without it?  If so, I can just import all the recovered keys then...